# kentico widget config button unclickable

Tags: kentico

Is there any way to make a widget's config and move buttons be placed at the top of the widget itself.

As it is one has to hover over a widget in order to see which one of the items in the widget zone it belongs to. This is impossible though when the content of the widget is not in the same screen space (I had to zoom out in the browser in order to get the below screenshot) unless you zoom out and then zoom back in.

In this image, there are 3 seperate widgets (red, white and green respectively) in a single widget zone.
[image]

Also, when the mouse leaves the widget the widget config/move buttons are no longer visible.

One solution is to right-click on the widget and then scroll up to the config wheel but this is not something I want to tell my editors they have to do.

Has anyone else come across this problem and if so, how did they solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when you have CSS conflicts.  You can use Chrome Inspector, Firebug, or IE developer tool to investigate and see if anthing is 'overlapping' those buttons (often a floating div is overlapping the buttons and intercepting the 'click')

Then once you figure out a css class to make it work, just add it to your style sheet with ".EditMode " before it, this is a special class that is on the body when in page editor.

Example:

```
.EditMode .MyFloatingDivThatsCoveringTheWidgets {
   z-index: 0;
}
```